# SUM () em uma clausula where - Mysql

Tags: mysql

A query abaixo trás resultados de um contrato, cujo atraso do contrato esteja entre 1 e 487 dias.

Agora quero `somar` os valores das `faturas pertencentes` ao contrato `invoice.value` e em seguida `filtrar` pelo `saldo` do `contrato`, cujo total esteja entre um valor e outro.

Mas não estou conseguindo.

Neste caso eu teria 8 resultados que se enquadraria na consulta abaixo, com o saldo do contrato entre `4 e 5 reais` e `atraso` entre `1 e 487 dias`, mas só recebo `1 resultado`.

O que estou fazendo de errado ?

```
SELECT DISTINCT `contract`.*,
SUM(invoice.value) as amount
FROM`tb_contract` `contract`
LEFT JOIN `tb_invoice` `invoice` ON `invoice`.`contract_id` = `contract`.`id`
WHERE `contract`.`creditor_id` = '5ddf5246-fed4-4e5f-538d-34df1e8cf9ee'
AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), invoice.due_date) >= 1
AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), invoice.due_date) <= 487
GROUP BY `contract`.`contract`
HAVING `amount` between 4 AND 5
```

Comment: Parece que precisa de algum ajuste no WHERE e/ou no GROUP BY / HAVING

Comment: amount é inteiro ? "> 1" não está "pegando" com 1 dia.

Comment: `amount` é decimal, o atraso está funcionando bem, a questão aqui é somente sobre o saldo (`amount`)

Comment: tirou o HAVING  para ver o resultado ?

Comment: Já tentei sem o Having, utilizando `invoice.value`, mas não consegui. Na verdade quando utilizo `invoice.value` me retorna um contrato que possui ao menos 1 fatura que se enquadra entre os valores, porem traz outras faturas do contrato quem contém diversos outros valores acima dos parâmetros informados. O que eu quero é somar todas as faturas do contrato e filtrar somente as somas que estão entre um valor e outro. Ou seja, todas as faturas do contrato não pode ser inferior e nem maior que os parâmetros de valores.

Comment: Note que HAVING é diferente do WHERE: WHERE filtra as linhas individualmente antes da aplicação do GROUP BY enquanto que HAVING filtra o grupo de linhas criadas pelo GROUP BY.

Comment: tentou HAVING  SUM(invoice.value) between 4 and 5 ou HAVING  SUM(invoice.value) between 4.00 and 5.99 ?, pois 1 'amount' pode ser uma coluna 2 o valor é decimal // falei em tirar o having para ver o que se trás e analisar o resultado // tb veja SELECT `contract`.`contract`,
SUM(invoice.value) as amount // distinct e group by juntos .... eles brigam rsrs

Answer (score -1):

Utilize o **sub-select** é a melhor opção para esse tipo de problema:

```
SELECT res.* 
FROM (
      SELECT DISTINCT `contract`.*,
      SUM(invoice.value) as amount
      FROM`tb_contract` `contract`
      LEFT JOIN `tb_invoice` `invoice` ON `invoice`.`contract_id` = `contract`.`id`
      WHERE `contract`.`creditor_id` = '5ddf5246-fed4-4e5f-538d-34df1e8cf9ee'
      AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), invoice.due_date) >= 1
      AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), invoice.due_date) <= 487
      GROUP BY `contract`.`contract`
      ) res
WHERE res.`amount` between 4 AND 5
```

Primeiro você realiza as somas e os agrupamentos no **sub-select** e depois realiza o filtro.